# Using .EMF (windows Metafile Format) in SSRS-report design

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, dynamics-ax-2012, .emf

I have a desire to use .EMF as image files when designing a SSRS-report.
Do you know if there is any way to do this?

I use visual studio and Dynamics Ax 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSRS does not support .emf files, so you will have to convert your images to one of the supported formats:

- JPG
- GIF
- PNG
- BMP

Also, if you do convert the files to another format and use them, I have found that the renderers used by SSRS do better the higher resolution you use. Using natively sized images usually results in an aliased mess of an image for me, so I always export/import my vector images at relatively large resolutions to the actual size on the report. This keeps them sharp on the .pdf and print renderers.

Comment: Hey, and thanks for the answer. How would i go about converting .EMF-files in runtime before the ssrs-report is generated( and using the converted image in this report )? Is this something that is supported in Ax 2012 somehow or should i use a third-party software for this?

Comment: It's not supported in stock AX, I imagine you would have to find a C# library that would do this (simply because I doubt one exists in X++,) and use that in a managed assembly to modify it, maybe store a converted copy along with the original. I don't do much with C# in ax, but here is an intro to the CLR interop, that lets you call C# code from X++: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc598160.aspx